# Stable jquery or flash uploader

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, plugins, uploader

I have been using a jquery plugin called uploadify for handling file uploads as it comes with interactive flash upload. but everyone on my website is complaining its not working. can some one please recommend me one that works in most situations. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, jQuery upload would be handled very different from a Flash-based upload. So you've to decide what's right for the site.

jQuery: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/
Flash: http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/

Comment: Just been checking out http://jquery.malsup.com/form/ does this work for <input type='file'/> and how does the user get notified that the file upload is in progress eg with animation or text. need something similar to whats done with fb or live.com

Comment: Form plugin will not provide any feedback. Like I said, if you need feedback that SwfUpload is great. Take a look at http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/overlaydemo/index.php.

Answer (score 0):

UPloadify its jquery and flash both............ http://www.uploadify.com/

Comment: i use uploadify but keep getting 2038, 408 errors. here is a link to an earlier post of mine concerning this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210567/jquery-uploadify-http-error-408